# How to avoid declaring database fields twice, once in database, once in a repository/model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tdd, separation-of-concerns

I recently began reading [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079).

The [author](http://www.amazon.com/Steven-Sanderson/e/B002H0STS6/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1) talks about creating repositories, and using interfaces to set up quick automated tests, which sounds awesome.

But it carries the problem of having to declare yourself all the fields for each table in the database twice: once in the actual database, and once in the C# code, instead of auto-generating the C# data access classes with an ORM.

I do understand that this is a great practice, and enables TDD which also looks awesome. But my question is:

Isn't there any workaround having to declare fields twice: both in the database and the C# code? Can't I use something that auto-generates the C# code but still allows me to do TDD without having to manually create all the business logic in C# and creating a repository (and a fake one too) for each table?

Comment: What makes you think that you have to declare the business logic twice?

Comment: "...having to declare yourself all the business logic for the database twice: once in the actual database..." wait, what? BL does not go in the DB, what makes you think it does here?

Comment: what I meant is you declare all the fields for each table in the database twice, once in the database itself, once in C# code, this could be avoided by using something like a LINQ To SQL's automated mapping class

Comment: edited your title because I don't think your asking anything regarding the Repository pattern, just data access in general.  Duplicating or mapping fields between the db and code has been a problem forever and I think your just asking for automated tooling options.  The repository pattern really doesn't say that you need to have a separate business and data access model in fact that whats ORMS are meant to support and handle all sorts of transformations in your mapping.  MS's implementations encourage persistence rather than domain model via autogeneration but its certainly not required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Entity Framework 4, you can generate POCO object automatically from the database. ( [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework))

Then you can implement a generic IRepository and its generic SqlRepository, this will allow you to have a repository for all your objects. This is explained here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff714955.aspx

This is a clean way to achieve what you want: you only declare your object once in your database, generate them automatically, and can easily access them with your repository (in addition you can do IoC and unit test :) )

I recommend you to read the second edition of this book which is pure gold and updated with the new features introduced in MVC 2
[http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-Framework-Second-Experts-Voice/dp/1430228865/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1289851862&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865)

And you should also read about the new features introduced in MVC3 which is now in RC (there is a new view engine really useful) http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx

Comment: yeah I read some about razor and it seems awesome, but since I'm new to most of the concepts in the book (pretty much everything except stuff <= LINQ) I'll first finish this book and then move on to others...

Comment: +1 to this answer also. I read the book you linked to on amazon and I too thought it was pure gold. It really is a smooth read and explains everything very nicely. Much better than the one by wrox with that nerd dinner crap in the first chapter that doesn't even compile until you sift through the forums for the book and find other frustrated readers that eventually figured out how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I understand what you mean: most of the POCO classes that you're declaring to have retrieved by repositories look a whole lot like the classes that get auto-generated by your ORM framework. It is tempting, therefore, to reuse those data-access classes as if they were business objects.

But in my experience, it is rare for the data I need in a piece of business logic to be *exactly* like the data-access classes. Usually I either need some specific subset of data from a data object, or some combination of data produced by joining a few data objects together. If I'm willing to spend another two minutes actually constructing the POCO that I have in mind, and creating an interface to represent the repository methods I plan to use, I find that the code ends up being much easier to refactor when I need to change business logic.

Comment: +1 to this. It's a little work to create the repository but sliding it behind an interface makes things so simple. Easy swapping out of business logic and easy TDD :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not declaring the business logic twice. It's just that this business logic is abstracted behind an interface and in the implementation of this interface you can do whatever you want : hit the database, read from the filesystem, aggregate information from web addresses, ... This interface allows weaker coupling between the controller and the implementation of the repository and among other simplifies TDD. Think of it as a contract between the controller and the business.